# UglifyJs Unexpected token: keyword «const» Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm developing ReactJs App and using `UglifyJsPlugin` in webpack for minify js.but wen i try to build, prompt bellow error.

`ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: keyword «const»`

[image]

Webpack : 4
babel : 7

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
}
```

**webpac.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|es6)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
       }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader'],
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg||woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true, 
              disable: true, 
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new Dotenv({ 
      safe: true, 
      systemvars: true, 
      silent: true, 
      defaults: false 
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css',{allChunks: false}),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),

  ]
}
```

Comment: Try remove `exclude: /node_modules/,` and see what happens. If there will be no error it means one of your `node_modules` library have `const` and it also should be parsed via bable-loader

Comment: @Arseniy-II thanks. After removing `node_modules`,its build without an error.but how can parse it via babel-loader?

Comment: I have added an answer for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin if nothing helps you.

Answer (score 2):

#### You should parse some of your `node_modules`

Problem is that some of your `node_modules` have `const` and they also should be parsed via `babel-loader`.

There are a few ways how you can do it. You may read [that thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031) and try what is better for you.

I prefer something like this:

```
test: /\.(js|jsx|es6)$/,
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(MY-MODULE|ANOTHER-ONE)\/).*/,
```

That will ignore all `node_modules` except `MY-MODULE` and `ANOTHER-ONE` modules. As result last two will be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below dependency

```
$ npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
 const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
 module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
};
```

happy codding :)